# changing UI and text of Updates available popup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

I working on eclipse rcp project where I need to add `updates available` popup
to my eclipse rcp application. I could show the popup, but now my question is
can I change UI and text of that popup. I want the look  of UI in my own desired.
Is it possible to customize the UI and text?

Please find the attached image.

[image]

Comment: How are you showing the current dialog?

Comment: It is automatically poping up after changing the setting in eclipse Preference->Install-update, there I set remind me everytime when eclipse started. So it comes automatically with default text and UI.